# How to prevent ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED errors following restart of Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, http, httpd.conf

I am running Apache 2.2.15.
I have installed a Comodo SSL Cert.
I have the virtual host directives shown in the code snippet at the bottom of this post.

When I restart Apache via `apachectl restart` I get no syntax errors associated with my directives. Yet the http daemon service does not start and all of my vhosts are down. I get the following error message in the browser:

**This site can’t be reached ... refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

```
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/abc/public_html
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/example_error_log
    CustomLog logs/example_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /home/abc/public_html
    ServerName example.com:443
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    UseCanonicalName On
    <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example_com_cert.cer
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/example_com_interm.cer
    </IfModule>
    ErrorLog logs/example_error_log
    CustomLog logs/example_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to check the system and apache logs for possible errors.

Comment: And where typically are they located @Khaled? I think I found apache to be at `/var/log/httpd/access_log`. How about the system log file?

Comment: System logs like '/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: `/var/log/messages` exists on the server but `/var/log/syslog` does not